# Why deleting several items from recylerView in MVVM does not work in android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-room, android-adapter, android-livedata

I'm writing a todo app to learn more about android architecture.
I implemented RecyclerView with adapter , which receives data from **ViewModel**. Now i trying to implement swipe-to-delete with "undo" button in Snackbar.

All works fine, until I'm trying to delete 2 items from **RecyclerView** at the same time. Only one item is deleted, second appears again. Problem only exists while snackbar not dismissed. I use

```
Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION
```

to handle when user push cancel on snackbar

```java
class FolderFragment
...
   adapter = new FolderListAdapter(getContext(), folderViewModel);
   folderViewModel.getFolders().observe(this, adapter::setFolders);
...
public void onSwipe() {
        Snackbar.make(getView(), 
R.string.folder_removed_message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .setAction(R.string.undo, v ->
                        adapter.undoDelete())
                .addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int event) {
                        if (event != Snackbar.Callback.DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION) {
                            folderViewModel.delete(adapter.getDeletedFolder());
                        }
                    }
                })
                .show();
```

```java
public class FolderListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FolderListAdapter.FolderViewHolder>
...
   void setFolders(List<Folder> folders) {
        this.folders = folders;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void onItemDismiss(int position) {
        mDeletedPosition = position;
        mDeletedFolder = folders.get(position);
        folders.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
    public void undoDelete() {
        folders.add(mDeletedPosition, mDeletedFolder);
        notifyItemInserted(mDeletedPosition);
    }
...
```

```java
public class FolderViewModel extends AndroidViewModel 
...
 public void delete(Folder folder) {
        folderRepository.delete(folder);
    }
...
```

See my RecyclerView adapter behavior on link below
[behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOnjO.gif)

trying to comment lines in adapter which deletes item from list in adapter -not work

logging setList() in adapter - viewmodel not updates LiveData because it work in background, but i dont know how to solve this

project on [github](https://github.com/SomeSimpleThings/simplelist)